# VBA Outlook Gmail sent item marked as spam. Sending from browser goes fine

Tags: excel, email, outlook

We send lot of mails with invoices in PDF format to our Clients. We have automated this with simple Outlook VBA code in this page:
[Outlook VBA to send mail with Attachment](https://officetricks.com/outlook-vba-create-email-with-attachment/)

The mail contains only a PDF attachment & few words in content with hyperlink to our website in signature.

**Problem:**
If we send the mail through Outlook VBA, the receiving side of mail shows this message.

[image]

But, instead of sending, If we save this mail in draft through VBA, then sync with Gmail, Open Chrome -> Gmail -> Drafts -> click send manually. The mails does not show the warning at reciever end.

Note: Settings in our domain like DKIM and SPF are set fine

We appreciate any of your ideas or hints to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook doesn't differentiate emails submitted manually or programmatically.

The following articles can help you to understand the cause why your email is marked as spam on the receiver's side:

- [How to Stop Your Emails From Going to Spam – 10 Tips](https://sendgrid.com/blog/10-tips-to-keep-email-out-of-the-spam-folder/)
- [12 Reasons Why Your Emails Go in the Spam Box (and How to Make Sure They Don’t)](https://optinmonster.com/11-reasons-why-your-emails-go-in-the-spam-box-and-how-to-make-sure-they-dont/)